# Access rights issue with Git

Tags: git, github

I tried to clone my work repo on my home macbook and got the following response:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I specifically remember configuring this machine to work with this github account and repo.  I ran `ssh-keygen` and create a key pair named `macbook13GH` (no passphrase).  I add it with `ssh-add macbook13GH` (i'm not sure exactly what this does and if its required).  I submit the ssh public key to my github accounts public keys.  Fetching it with `cat ~/.ssh/macbook13GH.pub`.

Now, I tried to add this local key pair to Github again and Github says `'key already in use'` which I suppose confirms that the ssh key-pair is setup between my machine and github.

So what then is the problem?  Perhaps it has to do with user accounts?  For example, my macbook git is setup to use my personal github account?

Comment: Are you an owner of this repository? Please do check settings -> collaborators and check if you or your organization is listed there and what rights it has for that repo.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely git is not pickup up the right public key (do you have more than one?).

You can create a config file for ssh protocol that specify which key to use for a particular domain.

The file is `~/.ssh/config`

And you can add an entry like this:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/macbook13GH
```

See [this website](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) for an interesting overview on this config file.

This will make sure that git (ssh protocol for that matter) uses the right key.

If that still doesn't work you can make git more verbose by prefixing your command like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone blablabla
```

You can increase verbosity until you get the right feedback, e.g.

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone blablabla
```

Comment: i tried the config file but no go.  i might want to verify that `macbook13GH` is in fact the same key i 'publicized' on github.  github lists 'fingerprints' on its webpage whereas `~/.ssh/` lists files and files.pub.  how can i validate which key is the public one on github?

Comment: also is `ssh-add` required for the ssh connection to work?  and is github accounts or git accounts irrelevant for what i'm trying to do?

Comment: if i run `ssh -T git@github.com` it prints my personal GH user account and not my work GH user account.  perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: @AlexBollbach The verbose option I mentioned should definitely give you a lot of insight about this. Have you tried running it?

Comment: i did. its white noise to me.  what about the fact that running `ssh -T` outputs the wrong github user.  it suggests that i'm "logged in" (i really have no fundamental concept of how ssh is connected to my github accounts), as my personal account.  whereas i'm cloning from my work account.  so naturally it would say 'could not read from remote repo'.

Comment: heres some log towards the end.  it seems to successfully authenticate with a public key but then goes off the rails.  i can't quite make out why. https://gist.github.com/alexbollbach/9961a4e47aad2cf4c9a910a362263476

Comment: Thanks for the log, is that all of it? seems to be missing some relevant stuff that should happen before the first line you have in the log..

Comment: i noticed that the auth had succeeded and decided to post only the subsequent portion of the log where things seemed to go wrong.

Comment: We know it's "successful", but we want to know if it's picking up the right key

Comment: The start of the log is vital... you'll get info about which key is used, etc.. could you submit the whole log?